# Start background job Asp.net 4.0 application

Tags: asp.net

I am facing one problem. I have to create asp.net 4.0 web application which should check a table from database after a specified interval and iterates over all records. I have to save some of the records having "xxxx" in column value. I created a class and this class has timer having 1 minute of interval. on tick method it iterates over all records and filter out the data to save.

I created the instance of this class in `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax` but this method does not fire. Remember this web application has no webform, not even Default.aspx

I cannot do this in windows service as hosting provider does not support windows service.

Comment: Get a different hosting provider. This should not be done in an ASP.NET application.

Comment: Seems to fulfil my requirement http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx

Comment: Check out [this post by Phil Haack on the concerns of running background tasks in asp.net](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) and some recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in a standard asp.net site will run unless the app is started by a visitor.

If you want scheduling functionality, you either need to create a windows service or write a small app which can be set up using the windows task scheduler (or cron if you're on linux)

Answer (score 2):

In IIS 7.5 there is an [application warmup module](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2009/10/14/now-available-the-iis-7-5-application-warm-up-module.aspx) that you likely could use for your application being automatically accessed, even if no user is opening the URL.

Another way would be to use a free keep-alive check service like pingdom or [tagbeep](http://tagbeep.com/).

That said, I usually always do such background tasks with a console application that I include in the Scheduled Tasks in Windows and let it run every now and then (e.g. every hour).

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET applications do not start until something is requested from them (an aspx page or asmx service for example).

And once they are started, they only live a finite amount of time before the process dies.

The only way I know of to keep a site alive indefinitely (although you still need to start it manually upfront) is to have a `Cache` item (just a throwaway object) with an event set up on expiration to make a page call, then to add a new cache item, which starts the process over.

This will make your app stay alive so that you can fire off your scheduled events.

There are of course problems with this method - if an exception occurs that kills the process, or if the server is restarted, then the "timer" will not start up again until a page is manually requested.